# Character counter should not display amount if amount is 1

Tags: python, loops

```py
def encode(message):
    encoded_message = ""
    i = 0
 
    while (i <= len(message)-1):
        count = 1
        ch = message[i]
        j = i
        while (j < len(message)-1):
            if (message[j] == message[j+1]):
                count = count+1
                j = j+1
            else:
                break
        encoded_message=encoded_message+str(count)+ch
        i = j+1
    return encoded_message
 
#Provide different values for message and test your program
encoded_message=encode("ABBBBCCCCCCCCAB")
print(encoded_message)
```

This code generates the following output: 1A4B8C1A1B

But if the value is 1 it should just display the letter like this: A4B8CAB

Answer (score 1):

Simply replace this line:

```py
encoded_message=encoded_message+str(count)+ch
```

with this:

```py
encoded_message += (str(count) if count > 1 else "") + ch
```

It should do the trick. Now it only appends the count to the string if said count is bigger than one.